# Why Does Power Steering Fluid Go Low?

Tags: honda, power-steering, crv

I am a noob in automotive mechanics (but very eager to learn).

I have a 2010 Honda CRV. The user's manual recommends adding power steering fluid to keep the level between the MIN and MAX level marks.

But assuming no leaks, why would the fluid go below the MAX mark?

I recently replaced the steering rack for this car and the PS fluid 
went below the MIN mark once within a year. Should this be a concern?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't go low. However, with a new rack, it may still be working some of the air out of the system, so it might be a little low after things get right. Overall, though, the power steering system is a closed system, meaning it shouldn't lose fluid over time unless there is a leak. Ensure when you're looking at the fluid, you follow the manufactures' guidelines as overfilling the system is bad for it (causes excess pressure, which can blow seals).